# Issue with onEdit after sending email in google sheets

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

here is my code in google script:

```
function Send(){
Browser.msgBox("Send");
   }

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lr-1, 6);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var date = row[2];
    var city = row[3];
     var status = row[6];
    
    if (emailAddress.match('@')  === null){
   continue;
    };

    var subject = row[4];
    var message = "Hey " + name + ", welcome in the team " + row[5];

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

    sheet.getRange(i+2,7).setValue("Sent");
      }
}
```

**Until here everything works fine. I would like then that when "Sent" appears in the 7th column, that the whole row where "Sent" is in, is moved to another tab.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var actionCol = 7;
  var nameCol = 7;
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
  if (e.value == "Sent" && colIndex == actionCol) {
       var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
       if (ss.getSheetByName("Welcome")) { 
           var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done");
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
       var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
            s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
          }
  }
}
```

**If I manually write "Sent" in the 7th column, the row is moved to the other sheet. But when I run the first function and that "Sent" appears in that column, the onEdit function doesn't work.
So basically both functions work but not together at the same time.

Does someone know a fix for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues:

- You are trying to trigger an `onEdit` function via a script but that's not how triggers work. The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) states the following:

> The `onEdit(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value
> of any cell in a spreadsheet.

Namely, `onEdit` triggers are activated only by **user actions**, not by scripts nor formulas.

- You don't need a separate function to check if the value is `Sent` and then delete the row with another function. After the email is sent you can move the data and delete the row, all within the same function.
- Last but not least, when deleting rows iteratively we change the structure of the sheet and therefore the data input does not match the updated structure. To alleviate this issue, we can store the indexes of the rows we want to delete in an array, and then using that array delete the rows backwards.

### Solution:

Assuming your codes work separately, this should also work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Welcome");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done");
  var startRow = 2;
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lr-1, 6);
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var colNumber = sheet.getLastColumn()-1;
  var delRows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = data[i];
      var name = row[0];
      var emailAddress = row[1];
      var date = row[2];
      var city = row[3];
      var status = row[6];
      if (emailAddress.match('@')  === null){
         continue;
      };
      var subject = row[4];
      var message = "Hey " + name + ", welcome in the team " + row[5];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 1, 1, colNumber);
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      delRows.push(i+startRow); 
      }   
  // delete rows in reverse order    
  delRows.reverse().forEach(ri=>{sheet.deleteRow(ri)});  
}
```

you don't need the `onEdit` function anymore so you can delete it.

Comment: An error message pops-up when I run the script:  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null
myFunction @ Code.gs:6

Comment: Additionally, I would like to remove the row for which the email has been sent but also store it on another tab named "Done"

Comment: @Fabien make sure you have a sheet with name `Welcome` and a sheet with the name `Done`. This will solve both your questions. Make sure the sheet names match **exactly** these two words. No additional spaces or different upper/lower case letters.

Comment: There was indeed a mistake in the tab name. Thank you again for your help :)